# Weyl Operators: Spectrum

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, operator-algebras

Given a CCR-algebra $\mathcal{A}_{CCR}(\mathcal{H})$ over a Hilbert space $\mathcal{H}$.

Then the Weyl operators are unitary:
$$W(f)^*=W(-f)=W(f)^{-1}$$
Thus, their spectrum lies on the unit circle:
$$\sigma(W(f))\subseteq\mathbb{S}$$
But why even all of it:
$$\sigma(W(f\neq0))=\mathbb{S}$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The spectrum is invariant under unitary transformations, thus it is rotational invariant:
$$\sigma(W(f\neq0))=\sigma(W(g)W(f\neq0)W(g)^*)=e^{-i\sigma(g,f\neq0)}\sigma(W(f\neq0))$$
Note that this excludes the special case:
$$\sigma(W(0))=\sigma(1)=\{1\}$$